# ModelBuilder works in editor mode, not when opened?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have made a pretty simple model. I can run it in the edit mode within ModelBuilder, and it works perfectly.

[image: Model]

As you can see, I have set some parameters, so I do not need to run it in ModelBuilder. When I try to run the model then, it does not work.

The processing window says, that everything succeeded.

So what am I doing wrong with my model, since it can not work outside the edit mode?

I have read some others issues, and they should make a script. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Is the output of the Dissolve tool set to intermediate? Right click on the green bubble and un-check it if it is set.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it does not work." What are you expecting (what happens when you run in edit mode)? I see that you are getting a "succeeded" message, but what doesn't happen when you run it outside edit mode?

Comment: @hornbydd the intermediate output thing solved a similar issue for me where the last tool in the model was not able to find the previous output because it was being deleted as intermediate. Thanks!